# Rails IIS 7 Missing disptach.fcgi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis-7

I have been trying to install rails on IIS 7. I have been following guide [here](http://ruslany.net/2008/08/ruby-on-rails-in-iis-70-with-url-rewriter/). However, after installing rails, I create a new rails app and there is no "dispatch.fcgi" in the public directory of the app. I assume that I am doing something wrong on the install of the rails gem or missing a dependency. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to have -D switch. Fixed